# Detect line where an error occured

Tags: php, line, notice

Is it possible to detect the line of code where the error is generated by php? 
For example, when there is an Notice alert, it returns:

```
Notice: Undefined index: XX in / home / YY.php on line 17.
```

Comment: "Where the error is generated". Do you mean when you throw a triggered error manually ? Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: <irony> Yes, on line 17. </irony> `set_error_handler` or rather `trigger_error` might help you.

Comment: @Sbls: Replace your `<irony>` tags with `<sarcasm>`. Unless you're American, in which case there is no apparent difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could register an error handler with `set_error_handler`:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $lines = file($errfile);
    $line = $lines[$errline - 1];
    print "Line with error: $line";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need place line into text of notice, you may use `__LINE__` too or also

```
$Line = debug_backtrace()[0]['line'];
```

if you have PHP 5.4 - or (if you have older PHP)

```
$Line = debug_backtrace();
$Line = $Line[0]['line'];
```

or, if you need to have more debug info (usable also in PHP 5.4, of course)

```
$Debug = debug_backtrace();
$Line = $Debug[0]['line'];
```

You can use also higher number than 0 - but mostly it is useless. And also you should be sure that array given by debug_backtrace has more than one item (that array has also item with key 1 or greater).